# Why does console.time show much lower time than the actual time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am testing a snippet of JavaScript's speed using the `console.time();` method in Chrome and Chromium-based Edge. When I'm running the snippet in the browser, it takes at least 2 seconds, but the displayed result of `time` is around milliseconds, What is happening here?

```js
var list = [...Array(50000000).keys()];

console.time("time");
var x = 0;
for (let i = 0, n= list.length;   i<n ;i++) {
  x++;
}
console.timeEnd("time");
```

I've tested this with `performance.now()` and I get the same result as `time`, which is really confusing however it works perfectly fine in Firefox.
Is this a Chrome/Edge bug? if it is, How can one submit an issue for chrome?

**Update**

Thanks to @vlaz and @Jax-p I found out that I've missed the array `generation time`:

```js
 console.time("time");
    var list = [...Array(50000000).keys()];

    var x = 0;
    for (let i = 0, n= list.length;   i<n ;i++) {
      x++;
    }
    console.timeEnd("time");
```

Comment: Before assuming it's *wrong*, how about you check whether it's *correct* first? You've timed all but one line of your code. What happens if you [time everything](https://jsbin.com/cilaveb/1/edit?js,output)?

Comment: Thank you, You are right, I forgot to consider that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating and spearding array with `[...Array(50000000).keys()];` takes over 1.5s in my Chrome **but you have timer start after that** *(You had. Before you change the question.)*. I am **getting same** (a little bit higher) results in Firefox. Can it be it?

Suppose there is also a delay before the browser even gets to execute JavaScript.

```js
console.time("time");
var list = [...Array(50000000).keys()];
console.timeEnd("time");
console.time("time2");
var x = 0;
for (let i = 0, n= list.length;   i<n ;i++) {
  x++;
}
console.timeEnd("time2");
```

Comment: No, it is not about that, there is a real diffrence between chrome and firefox in the example, just try these in the two browsers `console.time("time2");
var x = 0;
for (let i = 0; i<990000000;i++) {
  x++;
}
console.timeEnd("time2");`

Comment: @SeyyedKhandon, thats to be expected, the browsers have different javascript engines.

Comment: @SeyyedKhandon "*No, it is not about that,*" yet you edited your question to make it time the entire code and as if by magic now you get about two seconds of execution time.

Comment: Firefox is executing JavaScript in many cases slower but there is not that big performance difference as you mentioned in original answer (just like 10% in my case). You [can read more in mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40988) discusions.